# Randomly return a row number for a subset in the data frame

Tags: r, random

I'd like to be able to randomly return a row number from a data set, where the rows are a subset of the data. For example with the dataframe

```
x.f<-data.frame(
     G = c("M","M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F","F"),
     A = c("1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3"),
     E = c("W","W","W","B","B","B","W","W","W","B","B","B"))
```

I'd like to, say, randomly give me a row number where G=="M" and A=="3", so the answer will be row 3 or row 6. The number returned must be the position in the original data frame. Whilst this example is nicely structured (each possible combination appears once only), in reality there will not be such a structure, eg the combination (M,2,W) will be randomly distributed throughout the data frame and can occur more or fewer times than other combinations.

Comment: You want to get all rows or only one which is chosen randomly, e.g. by chance?

Comment: Just one row please, ie in this case either 3 or 6, with equal probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer of Sourabh and `sample` you can try:

```
# create a function using the sample function, which selects one value by chance
foo <- function(G, A, data){
  sample(which(data$G == G & data$A == A), 1)
}

foo("M", 3, x.f)
3
```

To test the equality run the function 1000 times using a loop for instance:

```
res <- NULL
for(i in 1:1000){
  res[i] <- foo("M", 3, x.f)
}
hist(res)
```

[image]
Seems to be an equal distribution.

Comment: Looks good and a clear explanation of how the task is done. Thanks to Souabh and Jimbou.

Answer (score 1):

Please try one:   `which(((x.f$G == "M") & (x.f$A == 3)))`

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe this :

```
row.names(subset(x.f, x.f$G == "M" & x.f$A == 3))
[1] "3" "6"
```

Comment: Good start, thanks. I could then just randomly sample one value, with equal probability, to chose a 3 or 6?

Answer (score 1):

Either of the other answers will give you a list of rows meeting your condition, but will not select one row randomly.  For a full answer:

```
sample(which(x.f$G == "M" & x.f$A == 3),1)
```

or

```
sample(row.names(subset(x.f, x.f$G == "M" & x.f$A == 3)),1)
```

or

```
sample(row.names(x.f[x.f$G=="M" & x.f$A==3,]),1)
```

Will all work.  There's probably two or three other ways to generate a list of row indices or names matching a set of criteria.